# How do I write a boost asio completion token which adapts to a non-asio coroutine library (PPL tasks)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost-asio, ppl

I'm trying to use Microsoft's Parallel Patterns Library's coroutines in my code, which uses Asio for most of its async stuff.

The cleanest way would be to define a token, `use_ppl`, which somehow behaves the same way as `asio::use_awaitable` but for [ppl coroutines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/interop-winrt-cx-async#overview-of-porting-ccx-async-to-cwinrt) (there isn't a ton of documentation about `pplawait.h` it seems).

For example:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#include <pplawait.h>

#include "asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp"

#include "use_ppl.h" // doesn't exist yet

concurrency::task<void> print_after_wait(asio::io_context ctx) {
  using namespace std::chrono;

  asio::high_resolution_timer t(ctx);
  t.expires_after(2s);
  co_await t.async_wait(use_ppl);       // adapter here
  std::cout << "print\n";
}
```

I've checked `asio\impl\use_awaitable.hpp` for some pointers, but it seems like most of the code is very specific to asio's particular `awaitable` implementation (which makes sense).

I've also looked at `cti::use_continuable_t` from [Naios's continuable library](https://github.com/Naios/continuable/blob/master/include/continuable/detail/external/asio.hpp), which seems similar, but again it's pretty library-specific.

Does anyone have any pointers for how to go about this? What parts of `use_awaitable` are "boilerplate" and which parts do I need to actually specialize for PPL tasks?

Comment: Note: I ran into some other problems ([case A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75189913/3554391), [case B](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75218245/3554391)) while attempting this, and I'm not sure it's possible with a token. Sehe's [answer on the second question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75228866/3554391) is a conceptually simpler way of going about the same thing using async_compose. See my comment for the modification that allows use of `concurrency::create_task` as the thread provider.